# C++, ссылка на метод уже существующего объекта

Tags: c++, методы, ссылки

Скажите, пожалуйста, позволяет ли `C++` разместить в объекте ссылку на метод уже созданного объекта (другого класса)?

То есть, что-то вроде:

```
A a;
B b { a.method };
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. В С++ есть "методы классов", а не "методы объектов". В С++ не бывает ссылок на методы классов, а есть только указатели на методы классов. В остальном  - ничего не ясно. Что такое `B`?

Comment: @AnT, `B` - это класс, в котором хранится ссылка/указатель на метод `A::method`.

Comment: Добавьте описание того, что вам нужно получить в конечном итоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `B` - это класс, в котором хранится ссылка/указатель на метод `A::method`

Пожалуйста

```
struct A
{
  void method() {}
};

struct B
{
  void (A::*ptr)();
};
```

Теперь, как вы и хотели, `B` - это класс, в котором хранится указатель на метод `A::method`.

```
int main()
{
  B b = { &A::method };
}
```

Однако без осмысленного контекста все равно не понятно, что и зачем вы хотите получить.

Comment: у меня есть объекты сцены. Я хочу, чтобы они сами себя отрисовывали. Передавать в конструктор этих объектов ссылку на целый `sf::RenderWindow` я не хочу - потому что в этом случае травинка будет иметь возможность вытянуть событие, изменить положение окна, закрыть окно, а не только себя отрисовать. Поэтому я рассматриваю возможность передавать травинке только ссылку на метод `draw` **уже существующего объекта** `sf::RenderWindow`. Это чисто экспериментальные изыскания, я понимаю, что все нужно делать не так.

Comment: ну а почему не сделать класс-наследник?

Comment: @MGNeo не нужно так делать. В этом нет совершенно никакой необходимости. Вам нужно в методы draw передавать не метод окна, а непосредственно объект канвы, или области на которой будет отрисовываться данный объект. При этом передавать надо либо по указателю, либо по ссылке, чтобы соответствующие изменения были "видны снаружи". Это общий подход в любой библиотеке, или структуре отображений чего-либо на общем пространстве отрисовки